# How can I access elements of cv::Vec4f by readable name?

Tags: c++, opencv, c++17, code-readability

I'm using the [`cv::HoughCircles()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d) function from OpenCV to detect circles in an image. The function takes an output parameter of type [`cv::OutputArray`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/dc/d84/group__core__basic.html#gaad17fda1d0f0d1ee069aebb1df2913c0) to provide the results. Based on the example code I am using a `std::vector<cv::Vec4f>` as output parameter, so the code looks something like this:

```
std::vector<cv::Vec4f> found_circles;
cv::HoughCircles(gray_image, found_circles, cv::HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 1, 100, 100, 10, 20);
```

Each element in `found_circles` is now a `cv::Vec4f` containing x/y/radius/vote values.
This basically works fine; but the code for accessing the details of the detected circles is not easily readable, because I have to access the members by index rather than by name.
For example, to sort the circles by radius:

```
std::sort(found_circles.begin(), found_circles.end(), [](const cv::Vec4f &c1, const cv::Vec4f &c2) -> bool {
  return c1[2] > c2[2];
});
```

It is not easy to see that `c1[2]` is the radius value.

Is there a way to access the circle details by name, so that the above code looks rather like this:

```
std::sort(found_circles.begin(), found_circles.end(), [](const cv::Vec4f &c1, const cv::Vec4f &c2) -> bool {
  return c1.radius > c2.radius;
});
```

For example, is there a way to access the `cv::Vec4f` elements with some aliased name? Or can I (with reasonable amount of code) create a custom data structure to pass as result parameter to `cv::HoughCircles()`, instead of `std::vector<cv::Vec4f>`?

I'm using OpenCV 4.5.3 and C++17.

Comment: `inline double radius(cv::Vec4f const& v) { return v[2]; }` or `enum CvHelper : std::size_t { radius = 2 };` and then `return c1[radius] > c2[radius];`

Comment: You could define an `enum { X, Y, Radius, Vote };` to access the elements more conveniently.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat: thanks, I went with your suggestion in the end. It's easy and looks quite OK.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot force a type to use names that the type doesn't use. You can create a type that wraps `cv::Vec4` which uses member functions to call the particular indices. You can even create non-member functions in the `cv` namespace whose names match what you want.

But a type has only the meaning that the creator of that *type* gave it. If you want specialized nomenclature, you'll need a specialized type.